# Image upload plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-8

I want to be able to upload the image via ajax. After uploading the plugin should show the user the uploaded image without reloading the page. User should be able to crop the image in case if they want to crop there face only instead of the whole photo.
The plugin must support Coldfusion.

Summary

- User should browse an image from there PC.
- The image should show up in the thumbnail part of HTML without reloading the page.
- The user should be able to crop a part of the image to be there actual profile pic.

If anyone knows any such plugin, please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you're going to be able to find a plugin that will suit all of your needs. I've build similar functionality, but every bit of it had to be pieced together from other plugins or custom code. My general workflow was as follows:

1. User uploads image via an iframe in the page (AJAX uploads are difficult to pull off).
2. The iFrame updates the parent page with the processed image through my cfm handler in the iframe.
3. Using a jQuery plugin, [jCrop](http://code.google.com/p/jcrop/), I crop the image, and send the resulting image back to the server when the user completes the form.

You're definitely not going to be able to find something to do all of this for you, so my recommendation would be to start on one piece at a time, and ask questions as you progress towards the final solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can achieve all your requirement by using "jquery.form.js" plugin. Just simply submit your form to a server site page(as you do in the normal case) using this plugin. Go through the URL below.

http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#getting-started

Answer (score 0):

Look at this plugin may be helpful uses php for handing backend functionality and easy to use

http://www.jqueryrain.com/?jKrB7Iva

Picture Cut is a jquery plugin that handles images in a very friendly and simple way, with a beautiful interface based on bootstrap or jquery ui, has great features like ajax upload, drag image from explorer, image crop and others.